# Save email parameter for resend function - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have resend email function and it works allright but it requires users to put email first for the token for verification to be sent if its not send after registration. I want to make it without input resend verification, the problem is if they are not verificated they cant login so i cant use `Auth::$user->email` to check his email and to send the link. How can i get his email parameter after he registers (it automatically redirects it to a page where says verify your account and there is a button to resend email if the first time didnt get sent.

**This is how my registration function looks like:**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = Account::create([
            'login' => $data['login'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'verifyToken'=> Str::random(40),
            'active' => (env('CONFIRM_EMAIL', true)) ? 0 : 1
        ]);
        $thisUser = Account::findOrFail($user->id);

        if(env('CONFIRM_EMAIL') == true){
            $this->sendEmail($thisUser);
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

**And this is how i want to resend email with resend button:**

```
protected function resend(Request $request, array $data)
    {
        $user = Account::where('email', $data['email'])->first();
        if($user){
        $user->verifyToken = Str::random(40);
        $user->save();
        $this->sendEmail($user);
        return back()->with('success', 'A link has been sent to your email');
        }else{
            return back()->with('error', 'Email does not exist');
        }
    }
```

But it doesnt work, where am i wrong?

> Too few arguments to function
> App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::resend(), 1 passed and
> exactly 2 expected

Comment: you can login without a verified email, but you can't access the routes under the `verified` middleware

Comment: So let him login but only on the verification blade. That way its easier to get his email to resend link?

Comment: give a hidden field in resend button and remove data from resend function get email from request

Comment: How to get a request from email if he is not logged in?

Comment: first file email from user and send email function like create function
after create function return back email to form and give hidden field to resend button

<form method="POST" action="{!! route(verification.resend) !!}">
     @csrf
     <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}">
     <button type="submit">Resend email</button>
</form>

Comment: @MahirMersimoski no need to login and store email in cookies only return back email and store in hidden field

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to have that `resend` button in other pages, you just need a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{!! route(verification.resend) !!}">
     @csrf
     <button type="submit">Resend email</button>
</form>
```

UPDATE:
if the user is not logged in, there is no way for you to know his email. You can use some cookie-based solution to store it when he register, however there is no way for you to know if that is the actual email he wants to use

Comment: I know thats allright, as i have it now it works with input email and all but for learning purposes i want to know if theres a way to store his registration email, and resend a link to that stored email without him loging in.

Comment: @MahirMersimoski if he is not logged in, how are you supposed to know his email? you can store it in a cookie, but it's not the right way to do it, because you don't know if he meant to use that email, or another one

Answer (score 0):

step 1

Make a form for fill email from user and call the create function

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = Account::create([
        'login' => $data['login'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'verifyToken'=> Str::random(40),
        'active' => (env('CONFIRM_EMAIL', true)) ? 0 : 1
    ]);
    $thisUser = Account::findOrFail($user->id);

    if(env('CONFIRM_EMAIL') == true){
        $this->sendEmail($thisUser);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

and give one more button there resend

```
<form method="POST" action="{!! route(verification.resend) !!}">
 @csrf
 <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}">
 <button type="submit">Resend email</button>
</form>

protected function resend(Request $request)
{
    $user = Account::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if($user){
    $user->verifyToken = Str::random(40);
    $user->save();
    $this->sendEmail($user);
    return back()->with('user',$user)->with('success', 'A link has been sent to your email');
    }else{
        return back()->with('error', 'Email does not exist');
    }
}
```

Comment: undefined variable user after registration.

Comment: are you using ajax for registration ?

Comment: Default laravel auth.

Comment: so simply use return back function with return user data

Comment: return back()->with('user',$user)->with('success', 'A link has been sent to your email');

Comment: I mean after i hit register it wont redirect me to the verification page where i added the hidden input button that has value of $user->email, and it doesnt register it as a defined variable

Comment: yes you did it ? if you did do same as resend give one more hidden field there